# iPhone SDK: AVAudioPlayer making noise when paused or finishes

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, noise

I'm playing multiple wav files (I tried using caf but same thing happen) with AVAudioPlayer. All the files are less than 2 sec, and 16 bit sound - file size is ~40kb.

I found it makes small noise (it's hard to describe, but a small sound like 'dub') in two cases:
1) when a play is paused or stopped while playing.
2) when a play finishes while another sound is playing (no noise when a sole player finishes its playing)

The noise is not loud, but when I do this play a lot in my app and it really annoys. It happens both in simulator and iphone.

I searched web really hard but couldn't find any similar issues, and I really wonder what the problems are. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here but have your tried setting volume to 0.0 before pausing or stopping?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but didn't work out. I kind of reduced the problem and will post below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting to my own question.

I don't really find the answer, but some observations might be useful.

1) It seems loading the sound file through NSData rather than NSURL works faster later in playing.
2) CAF seems a little better than wav, but not much.

I didn't have thorough experiment on this yet.
If anyone has clearer idea, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if it's doing it in the simulator then I can say with almost absolute certainty that it's only on the simulator.  I've had bugs with that too.  normally after playing a sound it'll go shoo shooo shoo (that's the best I can describe it). Try it on the device and see if it does it there.

Comment: It's almost same in the device too. Probably difference issues here, but thanks anyway.